# How to place a legend on top of the plot with ggvis

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggvis

In `ggvis`, if you want to change the position of the legend, you have to use the function `add_legend(orient = 'left')`, but it only allows you to choose between 'left' and 'right'. In `ggplot2`, I can place the legend on top of the plot with the `theme` function like

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Width, y = Petal.Length, colour = Species)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  theme(legend.position = 'top')
```

Is it posible to achieve this with `ggvis`?

Answer (score 0):

according to the ggvis documentation it's possible. The example below was taken from the document.

try this

```
mtcars %>% ggvis(x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, fill = ~cyl) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_relative_scales() %>%
add_legend("fill", title = "Cylinders",
           properties = legend_props(
             legend = list(
               x = scaled_value("x_rel", 0.5),
               y = scaled_value("y_rel", 0.5)
             )
           )
)
```

Comment: Thanks! That is close to what I need, but I was looking for a behavior more similar to the one of `ggplot2`, where the legend 'pushes' the plot area, instead of putting it over the plot. I need it for an interactive visualization, so I can't now in advance where is a good spot to place it.